# How do I create C++ map of object function pointers?

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a map of strings to functions.  When it's a simple function, I've seen how to do this like so:

```
typedef int (*GetIntFunction)(void);

int get_temp()
{
  return 42;
}

map<string, GetIntFunction> get_integer_map { { "temp", &get_temp } };

auto iter = get_integer_map.find("temp");
int val = (*iter->second()();
```

However, I'd like my function pointer to be to a function of a specific object.  And, I know which object I need at map creation.  Something like this:

```
class TemperatureModel
{
public:
  int GetTemp();
}

TemperatureModel *tempModel = new TemperatureModel();

map<string, GetIntFunction> get_integer_map { { "temp", &(tempModel->GetTemp} };
```

If you'd like to know why I'm doing this, I'm trying to read a list of parameters from an input file, get their values from the correct model, and then output their values to an output file.  I will also need to set values at runtime using a similar map.

Comment: Reopened. The purported duplicate was just a map of PMFs. This question is about binding an object and a function.

Comment: `GetTemp` is not static is a member function. `typeof(GetTemp) = int (*TemperatureModel::)(void)` not `int (*)(void)`. Use std::function

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to us old-fashioned types is to write a function:

```
int call_it() {
    return tempModel->GetTemp();
}
```

and store that function in the map in the question:

```
map<string, GetIntFunction> get_integer_map {
    { "temp", call_it }
};
```

A newer approach is to use a lambda:

```
map<string, GetIntFunction> get_integer_map {
    { "temp", [=]() { return tempModel->GetTemp(); }
};
```

Another approach (as suggested in the comment by Kamil Cuk) is to use `std::function` to bind the object and the function:

```
map<string, std::function<int()>> get_integer_map {
    { "temp", std::function<int()>(&TemperatureModel::GetTemp, tempModel) }
};
```

Caution: code written but not compiled; it may have errors.

Comment: Um. In your lambda ... wouldn't tempModel not be const?

Comment: @J.Doe -- could be. I'm tired. I've added a disclaimer. <g>